# Network path is not shared when trying to create folder with sharing everyone using c#

Tags: c#, unc, shared-directory

I have a wpf application in which i try to create folder on client machine and give sharing permission to everyone as i want to transfer crystal reports to those folders (unc network folder).I am able to create the folder with sharing permission showing as everyone with code but when i click the folder properties->sharing .It says network path not shared .
[image]

[image]

I have impersonated an administrator account and created the folder using below code ,i got from a stackoverflow post

```
private static void GrantAccess(string file)
{

    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(file);
    if (!exists)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(file);
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder is created Sucessfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder already exists");
    }
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

}
```

Comment: Are you an Admin?  Inside VS you are not Admin unless you click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: , I added myself as admin and ran VS as admin ,i still get the same issue.Folders created but not shared

Comment: Can you share as ADMIN.  Is issue only with normal users?  Did you make shared when login to machine or remotely?  The administrator has to be the owner according to the properties shown above.  The is a difference between EveryOne and GUEST.  Everyone mean that an account for user on the password server.  You may have Group Policy Issues.  Group Policy is used in corporate networks where many machines use the same password server.  Guest means there isn't an account for the user.